# Transfer charges between small and large ships

Tags: space-engineers

With the addition of Batteries and Merge Blocks, charge can be transferred between two large ships, a large ship and a station, or between two small ships, by means of detachable battery packs. Is there any way to transfer charge between a small ship and a large ship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Power flows through a [connector](http://spaceengineers.wikia.com/wiki/Connector), so if your small ship uses a connector to dock with a connector on a large ship, you will be able to use the  batteries/solar panels/reactors on the large ship to charge the batteries on the small ship and vice-versa.

As Philipp pointed out, power also transfers between rotors, so you can attach a large rotor to a small rotor head and use that to transfer power.

Comment: Rotors are another option. Large rotors can attach to small rotor heads and transfer power.